# Find the association of values in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table as shown below.
Table:

```
LinkA          linkB
--------------------
 1              10
 10             2
 2              5 
 4              7
 6              7
 7              3
 8              2
 3              9
```

I want to find the association of values in the table. It will link to any row that has one of its two values and continue with the newly linked row. 
Like that :

> Row 1 (1,10) -> Row 2 (10,2) -> Row 3 (2,5) -> Row 7 (8,2).  (1)
>
> Row 4 (4,7) -> Row 5 (6,7) -> Row 6 (7,3) -> Row 8 (3,9).    (2)

How to query table like that :

```
LinkA          linkB     SameLink
-------------------------------
 1              10        1
 10             2         1
 2              5         1
 4              7         2
 6              7         2
 7              3         2
 8              2         1
 3              9         2
```

Test table :

```
create table Data(
   linkA INT,
   linkB INT );
insert into Data(linkA, linkB)
values ('1', '10'),('10', '2'),('2', '5'),('4', '7'),('6', '7'),('7', '3'),('8', '2'),('3', '9');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution based on [SQL cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-cursor-example-code.aspx)

I also documented the solution for [grouping related data into data islands in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/group-related-nodes-and-edges-into-data-islands-on-sql-server.aspx) to provide more detail about the SQL script I share below

```
CREATE TABLE RelatedNodes (id int identity(1,1), nodes varchar(max))

DECLARE @LinkA Int
DECLARE @LinkB Int
DECLARE @cnt Int
DECLARE @Nodes1 varchar(max)
DECLARE @Nodes2 varchar(max)
DECLARE @Id1 Int
DECLARE @Id2 Int


DECLARE sqlcursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
select
    LinkA, LinkB
from Data
Order By LinkA, LinkB

OPEN sqlcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM sqlcursor INTO @LinkA, @LinkB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
---
    select 
        Id
    into ##tblId
    from RelatedNodes
    where 
        nodes like ('%,' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkA) + ',%') or 
        nodes like ('%,' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkB) + ',%')

    select @cnt = count(*) from ##tblId

    if @cnt = 0
    begin
        insert into RelatedNodes 
        select 
            case when @LinkA < @LinkB 
                then (',' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkA) + ',' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkB) + ',')
                else (',' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkB) + ',' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkA) + ',')
            end
    end
    else if @cnt = 1
    begin

        update RelatedNodes
        set nodes = nodes + convert(varchar(max),@LinkA) + ',' + convert(varchar(max),@LinkB) + ','
        from RelatedNodes rn
        inner join ##tblId t
            on rn.id = t.id

    end
    else if @cnt = 2
    begin

        select top 1
            @Id1 = rn.Id,
            @Nodes1 = nodes
        from RelatedNodes rn
        inner join ##tblId t
            on rn.id = t.id
        order by t.id

        select top 1
            @Id2 = rn.Id,
            @Nodes2 = nodes 
        from RelatedNodes rn
        inner join ##tblId t
            on rn.id = t.id
        order by t.id desc

        set @Nodes1 = @Nodes1 + @Nodes2

        update RelatedNodes
        set nodes = @Nodes1
        where Id = @Id1

        delete RelatedNodes where Id = @Id2

    end

    drop table ##tblId

    FETCH NEXT FROM sqlcursor INTO @LinkA, @LinkB
END

CLOSE sqlcursor
DEALLOCATE sqlcursor 

select
    LinkA, LinkB, GroupId
from Data
inner join (
    select nodes, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as GroupId from RelatedNodes
) g
on g.nodes like ('%,' + convert(varchar(max),LinkA) + ',%')
Order By GroupId, LinkA, LinkB
```

Outcome of the execution of above SQL script is as follows providing data for all rows of sample data

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you. This is the solution I need.  There are so many things to learn

Comment: Good to see that it helped :) I wonder if this problem has a graph solution

Answer (score 1):

Following Query using CTE should solve your question, just set the parameter in the first line:

```
DECLARE @Start AS INT = 1;
WITH CTE
AS
(
    -- Case Base
    SELECT LinkA, LinkB
    FROM Data E1
    WHERE LinkA = @Start
   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive Branch
    SELECT C.LinkA, E2.LinkB
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN Data E2
        ON  C.LinkB = E2.LinkA
)
SELECT * 
    FROM CTE 
    ORDER BY LinkA, LinkB;
```

More details on [Tips 4 DBs](http://tips4dbs.com/2018/11/27/recursivity-in-sql-server-with-common-table-expressions/)

Comment: Is this query worked? It provides related rows if you give starting node.